# How can I show $ (p \to r) \vee (q \to r) \equiv (p \vee q) \to r $ by Natural Deduction?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

The real question I have been given is:
                       $(p \vee r), (\neg q \vee r)$
and I need to conclude
$ (p\to q) \to r $

---

$ (\neg p \to r) \vee (q \to r) \equiv (\neg p \vee q) \to r $

I have the left side of the equivalence but I cannot show right side with natural deduction. Please help?

Comment: $(p \vee r), (\neg q \vee r)$: Does this mean $(p \vee r) \lor (\neg q \vee r)$ or $(p \vee r)\land (\neg q \vee r)$?

Comment: For the "real question", you have to use two "nested" $∨$-eliminations; consider the "outer" one : (i) from $r$, $(p→q)→r$ follows imemdiately; (ii) from $p$, using the second premise, you assume $(p→q)$ and derive a contradiction with $¬q$, concluding with $r$ and then $(p→q)→r$.

Comment: The two formulae in the title of the question are **not** equivalent.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I guess it's a mistake by the OP, while he wrote a correct formula in the context.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I didn't understand your comment can you please explain further?

Comment: As @zoli mentioned it is unclear what you are asking. The first description has a conjunction of two premises. The second has a disjunction as the premise. And what is mentioned in the title is different from both of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Use the following two tautologies.

$$
\begin{align}
\Big(\;\varphi\implies\psi\;\Big)&\iff\Big(\;\neg\varphi\;\vee\;\psi\;\Big)
\\[5pt]
\Big(\;\varphi\;\vee\;\psi\;\Big)&\iff\Big(\;\psi\;\vee\;\varphi\;\Big)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $P\implies Q$. Equivalently, we then have two cases to consider: $\neg P$ or $Q$. In both cases, you can prove $R$.